# Javascript AJAX load with url strings?

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, google-analytics-api

I'm loading javascripts lazy while testing Google Analytics API.
I have some static JS file hosted on my server (like googleAnalyticsAuthorization_v3.js, and googleAnalyticsApi_v3.js), I can query/eval them well, but I have no ideea how should I query/eval the following:
http://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad

My AJAX loader is straightforward:

```
function requestJavascriptWithHttpMethod(filePath, httpMethod)
{
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open(httpMethod, filePath, true);

    request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        _log('Request "'+filePath+'": readyState <'+requestReadyStateString(this.readyState)+'>, status <'+requestStatusString(this.status)+'>.');      

        if (this.readyState == this.DONE &&
            requestStatusString(this.status) == 'OK')
        {
            _log('Loading of "'+filePath+'" finished.');
            eval(this.responseText);
        }
    }

    request.send(); 
    _log('Request "'+filePath+'"...');
}

function requestJavascript(filePath)
{ requestJavascriptWithHttpMethod(filePath, "GET"); }
```

I tried to post the url, but no result executed (it actually returns with status code 0).

```
requestJavascript('googleAnalyticsAuthorization_v3.js'); //Loads, evaluates well.
requestJavascript('googleAnalyticsApi_v3.js'); //Loads, evaluates well.
requestJavascriptWithHttpMethod('http://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad', "POST"); //Nothing seems happening, returns with status code 0.
```

It should be act the same like I was simply included it into the client HTML code, like:

```
<script src="http://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
```

The console output is:

```
Request "googleAnalyticsAuthorization_v3.js"...
Request "googleAnalyticsApi_v3.js"...
Request "http://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"...
Request "http://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad": readyState <request finished and response is ready>, status <0>.
Request "googleAnalyticsApi_v3.js": readyState <request received>, status <OK>.
Request "googleAnalyticsApi_v3.js": readyState <processing request>, status <OK>.
Request "googleAnalyticsApi_v3.js": readyState <request finished and response is ready>, status <OK>.
Loading of "googleAnalyticsApi_v3.js" finished.
googleAnalytics_v3.js evaluated
Request "googleAnalyticsAuthorization_v3.js": readyState <request received>, status <OK>.
Request "googleAnalyticsAuthorization_v3.js": readyState <processing request>, status <OK>.
Request "googleAnalyticsAuthorization_v3.js": readyState <request finished and response is ready>, status <OK>.
Loading of "googleAnalyticsAuthorization_v3.js" finished.
googleAnalyticsAuthorization_v3.js evaluated
```

Can somebody help me out here?

Actually I just want to encapsulate all the logic to javascript, leaving no dependency on the HTML side.

Comment: According your code, the http method do you use is GET instead of POST, don't you?

Comment: I run the actual request by calling requestJavascriptWithHttpMethod('http://apis.google...', "POST"); The "GET" you see is just a shortcut function.

Answer (score 0):

You can not make Ajax calls to 3rd party domains because of the same origin policy. Normally you will add JavaScript to the page using

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "foo.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(script);
```

This will work cross browser, BUT the issue you have is Google Analytics uses `document.write` to add new script tags on the page. This means it will replace ALL of the page content. As a result, you can not add their code dynamically to the page after page load.

For async loading see Google's site: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncTracking

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Comment: I tried this method first without success. What you mean replace ALL of the page content? It does not, I mean I had this working when I was jsut simply included these files in <script> tags on the HTML side. But I'd prefer "hide" GA details from the HTML.

Comment: Ahh, you mean this (?): r.write("<" + T + ' src="' + encodeURI(b) + '"></' + T + ">")) - from https://apis.google.com/js/client.js

Comment: Yes, that is the document.write line.

Comment: I just want to HIDE from... ...from the codelines for simplyer reuse. Simply to have it elsewhere. Nothin' more.

Comment: Here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncTracking

Comment: Yea, actually I had this - https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api - working, but I have intention to refactor a bit. I'm just looking for possible solutions.